# Updating Property in an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Let's say I have a todo list array of objects:

```
const todos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    task: "Take out Trash",
    completed: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    task: "Make Dinner",
    completed: false,
  },

export default todos
```

How would you go about updating completed property to `true` in a functional component? I understand the code I have below is merely changing checked to `true`. I just need to figure out how to interact with the data source.

```
import ToDoData from "./data/tododata";

const myComp = () => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

 const handleChange = () => {
    setIsChecked(true)
 };

return (

 <input
     type="checkbox"
     checked={isChecked}
     onChange={props.handleChange}
/>
)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. if you want to keep the array of todos   as state & toggle the completed property of one of its members, then you need to pass an id with you onChange function which would look like this:

```
 const handleChange = (id) => {
    setTodos((todos) =>
      todos.map((todo) =>
        todo.id === id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
      )
    );
  };
```

but the better approach would be mapping over TodoData & returning a Todo component for each like this:

```
TodoData.map(todo => <Todo todo={todo}/>)
```

then inside you Todo component you can have:

```
const Todo = () => {

  const [todo, setTodo] = useState(todo)


  const handleChange = () => {
    setTodos((todo) => ({ ...todo, completed: !todo.completed }));
  };

  return (
    <input type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} onChange={props.handleChange} />
  );
};
```

this way you don't need to map over the whole array everytime one checkbox gets toggled